# JSON to Feature Changes Boolean Fields in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-desktop, geojson, arcgis-pro

I have a GeoJSON data I am opening in ArcGIS Pro using the JSON to features tools. The Boolean fields in the data gets convert to 0 & -1 values instead of true/false after this operation.

If this is expected behavior, is there any way around this?

I am using the data in another application so the consistency of formatting is very important.

[image: Screenshot of Values]

Comment: ArcGIS does not have a true boolean field (and as far as I know, nor do most of the mainstream databases it supports). What you could do as a workaround is to create a coded value domain with values 0 and −1, and descriptions true and false. Assign the domain to all your boolean fields

Comment: Good idea. Unfortunately my client wants to edit the data themselves. Thank you

Comment: Using zero for True and minus-one for False is *really* confusing. Using "1" and "0", or better, "T" and "F" would improve the UI experience.

Comment: @can-sucuoglu Do they use ArcGIS for editing? In that case it will become even easier, because they will get a dropdown with the options *true* and *false* and won't have to bother with the actual underlying values.

Comment: @vince Sure, but apparently -1 and 0 are the values generated by ArcGIS. Not much we can do about that afaik.

Comment: Yes the problem is 0 and -1 is auto generated. I converted all Boolean fields to "Y/N" fields. It is not ideal but doable. Thanks

Comment: To clarify how [JSON To Features (Conversion) - ArcGIS Pro | Documentation](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/conversion/json-to-features.htm) handles the JSON true/false mapping, `false => 0` and `true => -1`.  Although 0/1 is a much more common internal representation for false/true than 0/-1, -1 is just as truthy as 1.  I see the real issue not being true/false vs 0/1 or 0/-1, but that true/false gets mapped into a text field so all the values are true from a Boolean perspective, except a JSON null that gets mapped to an empty string and is false-y.